# Seperation of db connection in seperate class file doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j

Rookie here needing help. I'm trying to build a prototype with the neo4j .NET driver using Bolt. My aim with the prototype is building multiple methods for creation and searches in the db, but only one method to connect to the db - here I'm continuously having problems. I've Googled all weekend for examples, tutorials and traversed through the documentation and now I need your help.

Programs.cs

```
using System;
using DTUneo4jConsoleApp.Db;

namespace DTUneo4jConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            MyProperties something = new MyProperties();
            neo4jdb session = new neo4jdb();            

            session.Run($"CREATE (a:Person {{name:'{something.Name}', title:'{something.Title}'}})");
            var result = session.Run($"MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name = '{something.Name}' RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title");

            foreach (var record in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{record["title"].As<string>()} {record["name"].As<string>()}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    public class MyProperties
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

db.cs

```
using Neo4j.Driver.V1;

namespace DTUneo4jConsoleApp.Db
{
    public class neo4jdb
    {
        public static void Connection()
        {
            using (var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.Basic("user", "pass")))
            using (var session = driver.Session())
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I instantiate the `neo4jdb session = new neo4jdb();` I don't get i.e. the `Run()` method from the driver.

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing it like this:

```
public static List<IStatementResult> ExecuteCypher(List<Statement> statements)
{
    List<IStatementResult> results = new List<IStatementResult>();

    using (var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.Basic("user", "pass")))
    {
        using (var session = driver.Session())
        {
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                foreach (var statement in statements)
                {
                    results.Add(tx.Run(statement));
                }

                tx.Success();
            }
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

usage:

```
MyProperties something = new MyProperties();

var createCypher = new Statement($"CREATE (a:Person {{name:'{something.Name}', title:'{something.Title}'}})");
var matchCypher = new Statement($"MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name = '{something.Name}' RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title");


var statements = new List<Statement>();
statements.Add(createCypher);
statements.Add(matchCypher);

var results = ExecuteCypher(statements);

//you can now query result for each statement or
//your query your desired result
foreach (var record in results.Last())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{record["title"].As<string>()} {record["name"].As<string>()}");
}
```

In this way I can also create multiple records in a single transaction and get the result of all those as well.

Comment: Looks really good. Thank you. Once question though and maybe a stupid one, but you've stated "void", but `var results = ExecuteCypher(statements);` expects an output. That doesn't work for me, and I've tried with setting it to `public static List<IStatementResults> ExecuteCypher(List<Statement> statements)`, and return the ´results´ object, but with no luck. Can you throw some lights on how you handled that or have you encountered it before?

Comment: I have updated the ExecuteCypher function. This should work now.

Comment: Worked for me as well now. I found a couple of errors on my own side. I had the return statement too close to the for loop of the transactions, so by moving that a bit further out I could return the results as well. Also I had  to include `using System.Linq;`, that wasn't a part of my application. Thank you for your help. Appreciate it.